# What does "go with the odds" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I have stumbled on it in the 23rd episode of the 7th season of *Friends*. Here is the context:

> Monica: I’m making a list of all the things that are most likely to go
> wrong at the wedding. Now, that way I can be prepared.
>
> Phoebe: What are they?
>
> Monica: Well, so far I have uh, my bride’s maids dresses won’t get
> picked up, my veil gets lost, or I don’t have my something blue.
>
> Rachel: Hey! Those are all the things I’m responsible for!
>
> Monica: I had to **go with the odds** Rach.

Comment: I suppose it's the opposite of "go against the odds."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odds = the probability, likelihood or chance of something happening.  So, from her previous experience, Rachel tends to mess up and Monica is "going with odds" or assuming this.